# Can Sandhyavandanam be performed on grandparent's tavasam day?

Tags: sandhyavandanam

We do have our grandma's tavasam tomorrow, every time I have been told not to perform Sandhyavandanam during tavasam day of grandparents. Wanted to know the reason, is this really valid or we misinterpreted something. Some lights on this please.

Comment: What is "Sandi"?

Comment: Even in asaucha it has to be done but in a brief way